# Multiple defintion of main function in makefile

Tags: makefile, program-entry-point

I have written this make file and when I tried to execute it gcc compiler occurs  errors

```
 cc=gcc
CFLAGS=-I
LDLIBS=-lpthread
OBJECTS= MP.o serial.o MT.o
program:$(OBJECTS)
    $(cc) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) $(LDLIBS) -o program
```

and this is the message of errors

```
gcc -I MP.o serial.o MT.o -lpthread -o program 
MT.o: In function `main':
MT.c:(.text+0x2bf): multiple definition of `main'
serial.o:serial.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [program] Error 1
```

I am sure that there is no wrong in the 3 files individually
Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my make file?

Comment: First, adding `-I` with no directory is broken.  Either take out the `-I` or use something like `-I.` if you want the current directory.  Second, the linker error says you have defined the function `main` in both the `MT.c` and the `serial.c` files.  A program can only ever have one `main` function, so you cannot have that function defined in two places that are linked into a single program.

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my make file?

The error is not in the makefile, read the linker error:

```
MT.c:(.text+0x2bf): multiple definition of `main'
serial.o:serial.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
```

It's telling you that `main` is defined twice, first in `serial.c` and then again in `MT.c`

The problem is in your program, not the makefile.

(You do also have a broken CFLAGS variable with no path, but that's not the main problem.)